# Submitted from value is empty

Tags: php, codeigniter, android-service, postman

I am writing a backend service using codeigniter. I am getting `articleId` as empty when I test url on Postman. This means `articleId` is not accepting any value.

On older Postman version it is working fine, but on the newer version it is not working.

---

```
class getArticleServices extends CI_Controller
{
    public function getArticle() 
    {
        if ( ! isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) OR $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST')
        {
           echo "Invalid request";
        }
        else
        {
        $articleId = $this->input->post('articleId');
        echo $articleId;
        }           
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the first `<form>` tag of your html form?

Comment: or you can show us `var_dump($_POST);`also.

Comment: if you do  `var_dump($_REQUEST); die();` at the begining of your function What do you get ?

Comment: how are you submitting your POST request?

Comment: I am getting: array(0) {  }

Comment: Is `Content-Type` set as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in your postman headers ?

Comment: Content-Type →text/html (for the response I have received)

Comment: Then in postman, in the Headers tab, set `content-type` as key and ` application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as value and check your `var_dump` again :)